# How can I create a fresh (without any package installed) conda environment?

Tags: python, python-2.7, anaconda, conda

I am installing a software which needs some pre-requisite packages in a `conda environment`. There are some incompatibilities with the packages that I have already installed on anaconda and I need to install these packages on a fresh environment without any packages installed on that. I created conda environment by this command: `conda create -n test-nv python` but the problem is that every package that I want to install, it is showing a message representing that this package has already installed. Is there any way that I can create an environment without any package installed on that? 
While I am installing a package in new environment,

```
Reading package lists... Done
Building dependency tree       
Reading state information... Done
packagename is already the newest version (1.58.0.1ubuntu1).
0 upgraded, 0 newly installed, 0 to remove and 43 not upgraded.
```

Comment: Did you [activate the new environment](https://conda.io/docs/using/envs.html#change-environments-activate-deactivate)?

Comment: yes I activated,

Comment: Please add the the output from `conda install ...` as well as the output of `conda list` to your question. The more details you provide, the more likely someone will be able to help.

Comment: @Craig Thanks for your comment, `conda list` is now showing any package, but still I have the same problem

Answer (score 2):

I was able to create an empty environment by running:

```
conda create --name empty
source activate empty / activate empty (Linux&Mac / Windows)
```

You can confirm that it's empty by running:

```
conda list
```

Comment: conda list is not showing any installed package, but still I have the same problem